# Convert PDF documents to images and text for front end rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

This question is about converting PDF documents to image plus text
like Google Inbox do for client side rendering.

After conversion, what is needed would be the images for each page
and the texts on each page with its location and font sizes so that
the client side can select and copy the text.

There are a lot of existing solutions to convert PDF to images,
and to HTML. For example, [pdf2htmlEX](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX/) can
convert PDF files to HTML5 document. 
However, the first solution will 
not allow users to select or copy the text and the second one
potentially will not be able to preserve the original PDF
formatting.

By converting the PDF document to images plus texts, we can display the text transparently on the image.

Is there any tools and libraries that can help to achieve this?

This question is open for all server-side programming languages but personally I am more looking for node.js JavaScript ones.